# How to make Ubuntu Server 12 read keyboard input by the password line on login?

Tags: 12.04, server, keyboard, login, password

I have recently installed Ubuntu Server on my machine - successfully. However, the system does not read my keyboard input on the password on login. Is there something I did not do right? How do I go about fixing this problem?

Comment: Is this **12.04** or **12.10**? Do you mean there is no 'visible' keystrokes, or is the password **not** accepted?

Comment: It is 12.04.2 LTS. There are no visible keystrokes and the cursor does not move.

Comment: Are you still able to login?

Comment: I am not able to login since I the system does not read my input on the password line. I am stuck on the login screen.

Comment: I got it. I am now able to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passwords are meant to be secure, and therefore (to prevent 'shoulder surfing') are usually suppressed (or replaced with an 'asterisk' per character).

---

For a graphic interface ('GUI') that makes sense, and you may even have a dialog box option to 'view password'.

For a server (which may be remote) it is more secure to simply suppress any response, or visible cue, to what is being typed. *That may be confusing the first time, but will be second nature once you understand the reason.*

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind. Thank you for your assistance. I really appreciate it.